# Reference request. Characterization of existence of Riemann Integral.

Tags: reference-request, riemann-integration, multiple-integral, riemann-sum

**Question.**  Is there a mathematical analysis textbook that contains a theorem justifying the procedure described below that is typical of calculus textbooks?

Many calculus books of several variables and even many physics and engineering textbooks use the procedure of decomposing a region $K$ of the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ (respectively the space $\mathbb{R}^3$) into parts that are not necessarily rectangles $R_{k}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (respectively parallelepiped $R_{k}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$). For illustration purposes I have made the picture below for $\mathbb{R}^2$ setting.Pro

[image]

> **Formal description of the procedure.** In general for $K\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ the procedure is nothing more than taking a collection $\mathscr{P}=\{A_{\ell}\subset K: 1\leq \ell\leq M\}$ with the following properties:
>
> - for all $\ell$, the set $A_{\ell}$ is bounded, with non-empty and connected interior;
> - for all $\ell$ the  boundary $\partial A_\ell$ is of class $C^{1}$ piecewise;
> - $\bigcup_{\ell}A_{\ell}=K$
> - for all $\ell^{\,\prime}$ and $\ell^{\,\prime\prime}$ hold $ A_{\ell^{\,\prime}}\cap  A_{\ell^{\,\prime\prime}} \subset \partial A_{\ell^{\,\prime}}\cap \partial A_{\ell^{\,\prime\prime}}\neq \emptyset$ or $ A_{\ell^{\,\prime}}\cap  A_{\ell^{\,\prime\prime}}=\emptyset$.
>
> Then, take for each $\ell$ a point $\zeta_{\ell}\in A_{\ell}$ and make the limit
> $$
> \lim_{\|\mathscr{P}\|\to 0}\sum_{\ell=1}^{M}f(\zeta_\ell)\cdot {vol}(A_\ell), \qquad \mathrm{  with } \quad \|\mathscr{P}\|\overset{_{\mathrm{def}}}{=}\max_{1\leq \ell\leq M}\mathrm{diam}(A_{\ell}) 
> $$
> equal to the integral
> $$
> \int_{K} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.
> $$

I am looking for elementary analysis textbooks that are not from Geometric Theory of Measurement or books that justify such a procedure with results from Lebesgue's Integral or Coarea's Formula.

I can construct and prove a theorem that justifies such a procedure in terms of the upper and lower sums of a Riemann integral. What I need is an analysis textbook in $\mathbb{R}^n$ space that proves a theorem that justifies such a procedure. My purpose is to cite the result in a paper I am writing.

On the other hand, mathematical analysis books such as Pugh, Rudin and Spivak do not present any theorems justifying such a procedure.

Comment: A complete treatments of the Riemann integral over a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be found in Spivak  (Calculus on Manifolds) and Munkres (Analysis on Manifolds).

Comment: @RRL I have Spivak's book The Calculus  on Manifolds. And there is not one theorem in it that answers my question.

Comment: I could possibly help you, but I have no idea what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: Clearly $\int_K f = \int_Q f \chi_K = \sum_{l=1}^M \int_Q f \chi_{A_l}$ where $Q$ is any enclosing rectangle. Can't you start with that?